# How to find the optimal n_worker, threads_per_worker in dask and n_jobs from dask-lightgbm? Is there any correlation between these?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, lightgbm

I'm using Dask distributed/Dask LightGBM to improve the runtime.

I tried setting many combinations of n_jobs from Dask-LightGBM and n_worker and threads_per_worker from Dask for a 10GB file.

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                40
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-39
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    10
Socket(s):             2

RAM: 252GB
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding optimal performance is hard, and there is no algorithm to give you the optimal numbers for these.  They depend on your hardware, your algorithm, your data, and other complicated factors.

Comment: Okay. Given the above specification ( and original CSV size is 10GB), I'm reaching out if you have any ballpark numbers. I'm trying with n_jobs as 4 and n_workers as 2 and created df for blocksize 2GB.

Comment: I would need more information to give you a proper response, and even then I probably wouldn't know.  Your best bet here is to experiment a bit, profile, and learn a bit for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll do.